# I always get an invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 error with Mechanize

Tags: ruby, string, encoding, utf-8, mechanize

I recently installed Ruby 1.9.3. After that I always get this error message when I start to parse a webpage with Mechanize: "ArgumentError: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8"
I applied the "# encoding utf-8" at the beginning of all my source files. What can I do to avoid this annoyances? Should I use Ruby 1.8 or update to Ruby 2.0?

Comment: Which webpage are you parsing? Is your source file actually saved as UTF-8 (that might make a difference)?

Comment: Neither. That error message is an important indication that you are doing something wrong and don't realize it. Post more information if you need more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You could force encoding to `UTF-8` in case of mechanize I suppose it would be a bit different.

We were facing similar issue with ActiveRecord and Facebook attributes value getting set in Model. To solve this we had to use following even though at app level we had set encoding to `utf-8`

```
obj.attr.force_encoding("utf-8") if obj.attr.class == String
```

[UTF8 encoding issue in tilt](https://github.com/rtomayko/tilt/issues/75)

Comment: I usually parse Hungarian webpages, with special characters: éáűúőüóö

Comment: I reverted to Ruby 1.8 and now everything is fine. Maybe I will try Ruby 2.0 tomorrow.

Comment: Somebody proposed this method, but I don't know how to use it:
Auto-convert all mechanize pages to UTF-8: https://gist.github.com/dmitry/1653836